# I have offered a bounty for my question that has not assigned to any answer. Why?

Tags: support, faq, bounties

I offered a bounty for a question I asked, I accepted an answer, but the bounty has not been assigned to any answer. What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reported from the [FAQ](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty), the bounty is automatically awarded, within 7 days (plus the grace period), to the answer that respects the following criteria:

- the answer has been created after the bounty has been offered
- the answer has the higher score
- the answer's score is at least 2

This means, for example, that if you created the bounty to offer it to the answer that you already accepted, you need to manually award it; accepting the answer doesn't automatically assign the bounty to the answer that has been created before the bounty.

[image: screenshot]

If the answer is created after the bounty has been offered, accepting the answer is enough to assign the bounty to that answer, once the bounty is expired (7 days plus the grace period).